# Compute broadcasted strides

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `a` with some dtype `np.float32`. I want to know the strides of the array *after* being broadcasted without doing any memory intensive operations.

```
a = np.random.randn(1,5,1,1,5).astype(np.float32)
res = np.broadcast_to(a, (2,5,1,5,5))
res.strides
```

Output:

```
(0, 20, 0, 0, 4)
```

In reality I only have access to the original metadata of the array (not the memory). Is there something similar to `np.broadcast_shapes` that will also include the resulting strides? Or is there a way to write this conveniently without numpy?

Comment: What's the problem with what `broadcast_to` as you use it?

Comment: In my application I only have the shape and strides (metadata) of the array.

Comment: `broadcast_to` and sub-functions are in `lib/stride_tricks.py`.  You might also want to experiment.  Look at `a.shape` and compare it to `res`.  `broadcasting` can only add leading dimensions (with stride 0).  `broadcast_to` also appears to change size 1 dimensions to a 0 strides.

Comment: I had a look at the implementation, but they all seem to use the [np.nditer](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py#L348) to broadcast the array into ```itershape``` and I cannot figure out how to use the ```np.nditer``` without using an actual array. The ```np.broadcast_shapes``` only works because it can exploit ```np.empty(shape, dtype=[])```, which allocates no memory. But this empty compound type does not have strides.

Comment: On second thought, will **explicit** broadcasting only be setting 1 dimensions to a 0 stride? In that case I could just take the strides of the original array and set them to 0 where the dimension size is 1?

Comment: My guess is that `_broadcast_to` uses `np.nditer` because that's closest thing to using the c-api `nditer` that `ufunc` use for real-life broadcasting.  While it shouldn't be hard to simulate the broadcasting logic with pure python code, it wouldn't be as reliable or simple as just asking the compiled code to do it.  When used as an iterator, `np.nditer` is slow and clunky, but here it's just used to setup the array for iteration.

Comment: It sure looks like it just changes the size 1 dimensions to 0 strides.   But I haven't tested it extensively.  But why do you need this `strides`?  About the only time I look at strides is when setting up a `as_strided` call.

Comment: My application only uses the array metadata or interface if you will. The actual memory and array computations are done on a separate device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the `shape` and `dtype` in your metadata. You can utilize `numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` to create a dummy array with the appropriate `shape` and `strides` attributes (consisting only single a `bool` or something), of which you can pass to `broadcast_to`.

```
import numpy as np 
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
from typing import Sequence, Optional

def dummy_broadcast_strides(shape: Sequence[int], to: Sequence[int], dtype: np.dtype, strides: Optional[Sequence[int]]=None):
    # Create dummy array that only allocates one byte of space. A bool only takes a 1 byte of memory.
    # Meaning strides will be scaled by 1, must scale with appropriate dtype later.
    dummy = as_strided(True, shape=shape, strides=strides, writeable=False)
    # Multiply with dtype.itemsize to scale strides to dtype
    return np.array(np.broadcast_to(dummy, to).strides) * dtype.itemsize

if __name__ == '__main__':
    shape = (1,5,1,1,5) # shape of 'a' in your example
    print(dummy_broadcast_strides(shape, (2,5,1,5,5), np.float32())) # Must instantiate the dtype
    # [ 0 20  0  0  4]
    
    # Try really "big" array
    shape = (1024,1024,1024,1024,1024,1024) # shape of 'a' in your example
    print(dummy_broadcast_strides(shape, (2,1024,1024,1024,1024,1024,1024), np.float32())) # Must instantiate the dtype
    # [               0 4503599627370496    4398046511104       4294967296       4194304             4096            4]
```

Kinda dirty, but I like it.

Comment: This is great. However, ```dummy``` will be reading almost all of it's memory out of bounds. It's a good solution but it just feels prone to segfault.

Comment: Oh yes that's true. I was aware that it read out of bounds, but on my system at least (Windows10+WSL2) reading out of bounds doesn't cause any segfaults (i guess i haven't attempted to read "illegal" memory). Also, I thought that since you never really access the elements at any point (i think) you don't have to worry about reading invalid memory, let alone writing.

Comment: You might be right about it not reading any memory. In that case this solution is fine I think.

Comment: Ok, I just tested it with a very large array and I got a strange error: ```MemoryError: Unable to allocate 128. GiB for an array with shape (128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 1) and data type float32```

Comment: And segmentation fault occurred when going from ```(128,128,128,128,1)``` to ```(128,128,128,128,128)```

Comment: Hi, after some debugging, it seems to be that the `.astype` operation didn't play so well with the dummy array. Thus instead of using `.astype` I just multiply the `dtype.itemsize` to the strides to scale the strides correctly. I tested with various shapes, and it seems to be that `np.broadcast_to` catches all invalid inputs, so now there are no segfaults or memory errors for really large stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a slight modification of your `a`:

```
In [47]: a = np.ones((5,2,1,5),'float32')
In [48]: a.shape
Out[48]: (5, 2, 1, 5)
In [49]: a.strides
Out[49]: (40, 20, 20, 4)
```

The element strides is 4.  Strides for a row is `5*4=20`.  Strides for the next layer is also 20 because the shape, `1*5*4`.  And the top layer is `2*1*5*4`.

and broadcast it:

```
In [50]: res = np.broadcast_to(a, (2,5,2,4,5))
In [51]: res.shape
Out[51]: (2, 5, 2, 4, 5)
In [52]: res.strides
Out[52]: (0, 40, 20, 0, 4)
```

This has added a leading dimension with strides 0, and replaced the size 1 shape with 0 strides as well.

With strides 0, the shape can be anything.  `(0*40, 2*20, 5*4, 0*4, 4)`

Just to confirm that `res` is a view:

```
In [53]: a.__array_interface__
Out[53]: 
{'data': (56676960, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<f4')],
 'typestr': '<f4',
 'shape': (5, 2, 1, 5),
 'version': 3}
In [54]: res.__array_interface__
Out[54]: 
{'data': (56676960, True),
 'strides': (0, 40, 20, 0, 4),
 'descr': [('', '<f4')],
 'typestr': '<f4',
 'shape': (2, 5, 2, 4, 5),
 'version': 3}
```

We can replicate `res` strides with:

```
In [55]: b=a[None,:,:,0,None,:]
In [56]: b.shape
Out[56]: (1, 5, 2, 1, 5)
In [57]: b.strides
Out[57]: (0, 40, 20, 0, 4)
```